# Convert Base64 encoded image to a numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy, base64, python-imaging-library

I'm receiving an image via an http POST that is base64 encoded. It can be a JPG or a BMP. Now that I have the image, I can get it in memory. I found how to write it to disk and re-read it into a numpy array (Which I need to actually put into a torch.tensor but numpy will suffice for now).

HEre's what works for me but appears HIGHLY inefficient :

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import base64

base64_decoded = base64.b64decode(test_image_base64_encoded)

with open("out.jpg", "wb") as out_file:
    out_file.write(base64_decoded)

image = Image.open("out.jpg")
image_np = np.array(image)
image_torch = torch.tensor(np.array(image))
```

It feels extremely useless to have to write the array to out.jpg to reread it right after into an array. There must be a better way. I've tried some things where it ends up in a 1D array... and my image is a 2D array in my case (BW image).

```py
nparr = np.fromstring(base64.b64decode(test_image), np.uint8)
```

would yield when nparr.shape = (694463,)
when image_np.shape = (2048, 3072)

Any idea how I could represent to np.array something like Image.frombase64 :) ? I know it doesn't exists per say but that would be great if it could somehow interpret the "file" without having to save it to disk first.

Comment: It looks like you're using `Image` from `PIL`, is that correct? It would be good to provide a complete example, so people can see what's needed to make the example work. Note that PIL has a `.frombytes()` method for 'Image', which is what you may be looking for https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#constructing-images

Comment: That is correct. The PIL.Image.frombytes() didn't work for me. I'll add the included libraries there. And your suggested answer works, thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you're using PIL, but you don't know the image type or dimensions:

```
from PIL import Image
import base64
import io
import numpy as np
import torch

base64_decoded = base64.b64decode(test_image_base64_encoded)

image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64_decoded))
image_np = np.array(image)
image_torch = torch.tensor(np.array(image))
```

`io.BytesIO` is the key thing you're missing, I think.

Comment: This is the error I get using this code `UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ff17ae7aae0>`

Comment: @henrynavarro You should probably post a question of your own, with the exact code you're using. I just checked, but this code works as intended, as long as `test_image_base64_encoded` is a string representing a base64 encoded image, like the ones you can make here https://elmah.io/tools/base64-image-encoder/